# Java Reflection getConstructor method

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, extends, getconstructor

Lets say I have classes `A` and `B`, where `B` extends `A`. I also have a constructor in `B` with one argument which is of type `A`. I also have an object of type `B` called `bObj`.

Is there a way to call `B.class.getConstructor(new Class[] { bObj.getClass() })` and get the constructor since `B` extends `A`? At the moment I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: What about using `B.class.getConstructors()`, find the ones that take exactly one argument, and check whether `A.class` `isAssignableFrom` this one?

Comment: arne.b This is one way of doing it but I thought it could actually be easier.

Nandkumar Yes, it is public.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think I'm satisfied with what you provided as an answer. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the [`ConstructorUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).
They have all manners of constructor discovery methods.

Your case should be covered by "[Matching Accessible Constructors](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleConstructor-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class...-)".

[Here](https://github.com/anathema/anathema/blob/master/Platform/src/net/sf/anathema/initialization/reflections/ReflectionsInstantiater.java#L74) is an example of the method used in context.
Basically, you call it like this:

```
 private <T> T instantiate(Class<?> input, Object parameter) {
  try {
    Constructor<?> constructor = ConstructorUtils.getMatchingAccessibleConstructor(input, parameter.getClass());
    return (T) constructor.newInstance(parameter);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //handle various exceptions
  } 
}
```

Comment: This works flawlessly and is - in my opinion - quite elegant. Two additional hints: (1) If you declare the "input" parameter as `Class<T> input`, you can prevent casting the return value. (2) `ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(Class<T> cls, Object... args)` combines getting the constructor and creating a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

No, the methods which search for you expect exact parameters. So when you look for a constructor, method or field using find/search methods of the reflection API, the API uses `equals()` to find matches.

If you need the same logic that the Java compiler would use, you will need to use a framework like [FEST Reflect](https://code.google.com/p/fest/) or [commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). Or you must call `getConstructors()` and write your own filter code.

At first glance, this seems stupid: If the Java compiler can do it, why can't the Reflection API? There are two reasons: First, the Java runtime doesn't need to search which method to call because the compiler already selected the correct method.

The second reason is that the Reflection API was always "second best". It can do everything but the goal was never to make it really easy/friendly to use (at least, that's what I think every time I use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

if your constructor is not public (or if it's class is not public), or not accessible from your code scope, it will not be returned through

```
Class.getConstructor()
```

try

```
Class.getDeclaredConstructor()
```

instead